# Can we use Apache Solr for relational database like mysql?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new to **Apache Solr** I need to know weather **Apache Solr** is realy good for relational database like mysql. Why am I looking for **Apache Solr** is I have large Database with relational mapping with **FK** data retrieving is really very slow so i am looking for some searching engine or algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , Apache solr is very good for relational database like MYSql and Oracle.

You can use the data import handler (DIH) of solr.

Index the data using DIH and check the performance.

Here are link which will help you to achieve the same

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler

http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/01/how-to-use-solr-data-import-handler-to.html

Comment: if that answers the question ..feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Is it possible to replace 0.5,1 GB database with it?, I means how bigger it can handle.

Comment: @Adrian : Is the 0.5 GB the total size of the database or the the single row of the database? I have currently indexed 100 GB of data.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I have 5 Lakh records that total 500 MB DB. The data record mostly large String. It looks like a nice idea. I will check it this weekend.

Answer (score 3):

You (probably) don't want to use Solr as a database, but using it together with a relational DB is a very common use-case.

One of many reasons for not using Solr as your primary data store is that transformations on input will be lossy, and up until the last years, could not update single fields. Seeing as changes to fields will not be propagated to existing data as well, it'll be probably be ridden by problems trying to use it as your single store.

Use a different technology to store data, but index it to Solr and do search queries against it to offload your primary data store.

Comment: Than I can use mysql as database and indexing with solr will solve my data loading problem right.

Comment: It might. Impossible to say without knowing where your performance issues are - primary keys lookups in RDBMs should be a use-case that the database is heavily optimized for as well.

Comment: query fetch is quit good. Actually I'm using hibernate framework for fetching data so I have a doubt it might take a time.